# Trying to understand why Swift code compiles but can't link due to undefined symbols

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a issue with the link phase failing due to undefined symbols. I'm looking to understand the general issue rather than a copy/paste solution for my specific setup.

Let's say I have 2 frameworks, and 1 target. framework B is linked to framework A and the target links with framework A only. The target does not link directly with framework B.

Swift files that contain "import A" are successfully compiling even though they reference objects contained in framework B. I guessing this is because the linkage between A > B makes all of B available when I import A.

However during the link phase, I get undefined symbol errors for anything contained in framework B. Adding "import B" in my file will again compile successfully, but still fail with the same link errors. Linking only succeeds If I directly link the target framework B.

I'd like for either of two scenarios to work:

1. Linking with framework A and "import A" also makes the link phase see symbols from framework B
2. Compilation fails to find objects in framework B unless I directly link with framework B and "import B"

Can someone shed some light on which of these scenarios is the "correct" one and why?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Option 1 can work if you create what is called an umbrella framework.  Everything I've read suggests that nobody except Apple should do that, however.  Since I know much less about import mechanics, I'll avoid commenting on option 2.  :)